# Database record not updated

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, record

Hi everyone I'm new to here, I have problem to update my database record in VB ASP.NET webform. My code below will return dialog box that says record updated successfully when cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 but the record in database not being updated in fact. Sorry for my bad english. Please help thanks in advance.

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim staffUsername As String = Session("StaffUsername").ToString()
    Dim staffFNm As String = txtStaffFNm.Text
    Dim staffLNm As String = txtStaffLNm.Text
    Dim staffEmail As String = txtStaffCpnyEmail1.Text + txtStaffCpnyEmail2.Text
    Dim staffBDay As String = txtBirthday.Text
    Dim staffPhone As String = txtPhoneNo.Text
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SupportSystemDB").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()

        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("UPDATE STAFF SET StaffFNm = @staffFNm, StaffLNm = @staffLNm, StaffEmail = @staffEmail, StaffBirthday = @staffBDay, StaffPhone = @staffPhone  WHERE StaffUsernm = @staffUsernm", con)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffFNm", staffFNm)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffLNm", staffLNm)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffEmail", staffEmail)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffBDay", staffBDay)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffPhone", staffPhone)
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffUsernm", staffUsername)
        If myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Your Account Info Has Been Successfully Updated.');</script>")
            con.Close()
        Else
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Record Update Failed.');</script>")
        End If


    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: If `ExecuteNonQuery` returns a value greater than zero then your database was updated and you're just not looking for the change properly.  What does your connection string look like?

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney , yeah my code return feedback telling record has been updated successfully but when I check the record in the database it doesn't change any.

Comment: @ZhenChua      How is your Environment set up? I've had issues when I try to call for instance the table "Staff" when in reality I had to use "Database.dbo.Staff" in order to update the correct table.

Comment: I hope there are no trigger set for update, which would delete the record for some particular update in the table.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, I misunderstood your question just now.
Below is my connection string in web.config : 

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SupportSystemDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=ASPERTI-PC\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=dbSupportSystem; User Id=sa; password=Sa!23456;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Are you saying you get _Your Account Info Has Been Successfully Updated._ when you update but when you check the database nothing is updated? Could it be you are updating a _different_ database? Check your connection string. I'd also advise not to show us your connection string users / passwords. This is a public site. You can edit your comment (within 5 mins of posting) or delete altogether to remove.

Comment: @Bugs Yes, my problem is same as you mentioned. I think I didn't update the wrong database as my select statement works well on Page Load.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. As already said, if `ExecuteNonQuery` is returning a value greater than zero then the update did happen somewhere. I take it you don't have any triggers on your table as already said and you're not running anything else that could remove the row?

Comment: You probably want to always close your connection (con.close), even if you get an error, because you will get an connection already open the second time.